# MongoDB insert a document for every documents in another collection

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongodb-query, document, mongodb-update

I have a collection (`users`) containing some documents like so :

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("56d45406be05db4022be51f9"),
    morecontent : ""
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("56d45406be05db3021be32e3"),
    morecontent : ""
}
```

I would like to create a new document for every entry in the `user` collection. 
The documents would be created from a notification object like this :

```
{
    type: 'alert',
    msg: 'This is important'
}
```

The collection `notifications` should look something like this :

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("56d45406be05db3021bf20a1"),
    someoldcontent: "This was here before the request"
},
{
    _id : ObjectId("56d45406be05db4022be20b1"),
    user: ObjectId("56d45406be05db4022be51f9"),
    type: 'alert',
    msg: 'This is important'
},
{
    _id : ObjectId("56d45406be05db3021be32e3"),
    user: ObjectId("56d45406be05db3021be32e3"),
    type: 'alert',
    msg: 'This is important'
}
```

Is there any way to do this in a mongodb request?

Comment: what will you use as db-client? (node, java, c#) or you want just to have a query to perform that?

Comment: @profesor79 I would use nodejs

Comment: I am not sure that I got you question right  
1. user performs action
2. applications makes insert into notifications collection using user _id

Comment: @profesor79 I want to insert an object in the notification collection for every user document there is in the user collection. The notification will be the same for every users except it should have a different user_id. The notifications should be in the notifications collection.

Comment: let's chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104903/mongo-queries-issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to `professor79` for helping me a lot with the question.

After lots of effort, the query was found. We used the aggregation framework in order to succeed.

The only 2 aggregations needed are `$project` and `$out`. The `$out` will automatically take care of the new `_id` in the `notification` document.

Given this collection named `user` :

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("56d45406be05db4022be51f9"),
    morecontent : ""
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("56d45406be05db3021be32e3"),
    morecontent : ""
}
```

We want to create a notification containing the same `msg` and `type` field for every document in the `user` collection.
Each notifications will be in the `notifications` collection an will have as a reference its corresponding `userId`.

Here is the query to achieve such a result :

```js
db.user.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            userId: '$_id',
            type: { $literal: 'danger' },
            msg: { $literal: 'This is a message' },
        },
    },
    { $out: 'notifications' },
])
```

The output in `notifications` collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d6112e197b4ea11a87de1a"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("56d45406be05db4022be51f9"),
    "type" : "danger",
    "msg" : "This is a message"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d6112e197b4ea11a87de1b"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("56d45406be05db3021be32e3"),
    "type" : "danger",
    "msg" : "This is a message"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As we have some chat to clarify problem:

the steps are needed to perform this operation server side:

> 1. first step - match > get users id
> 2. project ids to new documents as required
> 3. out -> store output in notification collection